# Is there a skeptic.SE chat?

Tags: support, chat

We don't have a chat link on our frontpage like the other SE sites. Don't we get one during the beta or what is the reason for that?

I would think a chat would be very useful during these early days of the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is!  I see a link in the header both here and on the main site:

[image: header]

Comment: I was looking on the right side for link to the active chat rooms, I totally forgot that there is also one link at the top